# MATLAB Perceptron

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now. I cant seem to figure out why I have a percentage error in the thousands. I'm trying to figure out a perceptron between X1 and X2 which are Gaussian distributed data sets with distinct means and identical covariances. My code:

```
N=200;
X = [X1; X2];
X = [X ones(N,1)]; %bias
y = [-1*ones(N/2,1); ones(N/2,1)]; %classification

%Split data into training and test 
ii = randperm(N);
Xtr = X(ii(1:N/2),:);
ytr = X(ii(1:N/2),:);
Xts = X(ii(N/2+1:N),:);
yts = y(ii(N/2+1:N),:);

w = randn(3,1);
eta = 0.001;
%learn from training set
for iter=1:500 
j = ceil(rand*N/2);
if( ytr(j)*Xtr(j,:)*w < 0)
    w = w + eta*Xtr(j,:)'; 
end
end

%apply what you have learnt to test set
yhts = Xts * w;
disp([yts yhts])
PercentageError = 100*sum(find(yts .*yhts < 0))/Nts;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You are missing some definitions - `X1`, `X2` (which are 100x2 matrices), `Nts` (which I'm guessing is just `N/2`) - without them your problem cannot be replicated (or at least not easily).

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in your error calculation.

On this line:

```
PercentageError = 100*sum(find(yts .*yhts < 0))/Nts;
```

The `find` is returning indices of the matching items. For your accuracy measure you don't want those, you just want the count:

```
PercentageError = 100*sum( yts .*yhts < 0 )/Nts;
```

If I generate `X1 = randn(100,2); X2 = randn(100,2);` and assume `Nts=100`, I get 2808% for your code, and expected 50% error (no better than guessing because my test data cannot be separated) for the corrected version.

Update - the perceptron model had a more subtle bug too, see: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2353/matlab-perceptron

Comment: Thank you! This got my error down to about 50%. I've used other methods (bayes) and the data is, to a large extent, separable. I believe the percentage error should be a lot lesser

Comment: A basic perceptron will only find linear separations in the data. Perhaps you could ask another question ( on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ) if your model is not doing what you expect. You would need to give the exact code you use to generate X1 and X2 if so, as well as your model, because you may be making assumptions about how the data are separable into the classes.